# Java server JavaScript client WebSockets

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, java-websocket

I'm trying to do a connection between a server in Java and a JavaScript client but I'm getting this error on client side:

> **WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:4444/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response**

It maybe stays on OPENNING state because the `connection.onopen` function is never called. The `console.log('Connected!')` isn't being called.

Could someone let me know what is going wrong here?

**Server**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444)) {
            GameProtocol gp = new GameProtocol();

            ServerThread player= new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept(), gp);
            player.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

    }

}
```

**ServerThread**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerThread extends Thread{

    private Socket socket = null;
    private GameProtocol gp;

    public ServerThread(Socket socket, GameProtocol gp) {
        super("ServerThread");
        this.socket = socket;
        this.gp = gp;
    }

    public void run() {

        try (
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                socket.getInputStream()));
                ) {
            String inputLine, outputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                outputLine = gp.processInput(inputLine);
                System.out.println(outputLine);
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**GameProtocol**

```
public class GameProtocol {

    public String processInput(String theInput) {

        String theOutput = null;

        theOutput = theInput;

        return theOutput;
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:4444');

connection.onopen = function () {
    console.log('Connected!');
    connection.send('Ping'); // Send the message 'Ping' to the server
};

// Log errors
connection.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
};

// Log messages from the server
connection.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log('Server: ' + e.data);
};
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked just fine... What browser do you use for your test? Also, is there any firewall that could block/mess with the response?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 55. I thing not. Plus, if I print out the response on server side I got the message I put above.

Comment: All seems ok... Maybe, try another port? Like 12000 or higher, I heard that some systems don't like low port numbers... I'm just speculating, because I have no idea what could be the difference between our set-ups...

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but the problem keeps the same. You tried in Chrome and it's not printing the WebSocket error?

Comment: Yes, I'm using chrome Version 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit) and I started my server in eclispe and when I load the page with my script, the server writes: "A client connected."

Comment: Ok, but it's on the server side. On client side, if you go to the chrome console on chrome dev tools doesn't appear the WebSocket error?

Comment: Oh, you said in your question that you have an error on the server side... I'll try it later and tell you if i get an error in chrome.

Comment: I've edited the post. I've made some changes on code and now the error is different. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if your local computer firewall is allowing this port

Comment: I haven't a firewall. I thing the client is waiting a response from the server and it's not receiving it. Am I right? And so it won't change the state from OPENNING

Comment: I will give it try tomorrow as it is late night for me and let you know

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To start with, both your code looks identical the Java and JavaScript one. Both work for what they are design to, but the facts is that you are trying to connect a WebSocket client to a socket server.

As I know they are two different things regarding this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973622/difference-between-socket-and-websocket).

I have never tried it your way. That said if I have a network application that use socket than it would be pure client/server socket, and if it was a web application than I would use WebSocket on both side as well.

**So far so good..**

To make this work, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292624/java-websocket-host) suggests to use any available WebSocket on server side and your problem is solved.

I am using [WebSocket for Java](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) and here is a sample implementation that I have tested with your client code and it works, both on client and server side.

```
import org.java_websocket.WebSocket;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ClientHandshake;
import org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class WebsocketServer extends WebSocketServer {

    private static int TCP_PORT = 4444;

    private Set<WebSocket> conns;

    public WebsocketServer() {
        super(new InetSocketAddress(TCP_PORT));
        conns = new HashSet<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket conn, ClientHandshake handshake) {
        conns.add(conn);
        System.out.println("New connection from " + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(WebSocket conn, int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
        conns.remove(conn);
        System.out.println("Closed connection to " + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket conn, String message) {
        System.out.println("Message from client: " + message);
        for (WebSocket sock : conns) {
            sock.send(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(WebSocket conn, Exception ex) {
        //ex.printStackTrace();
        if (conn != null) {
            conns.remove(conn);
            // do some thing if required
        }
        System.out.println("ERROR from " + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress());
    }
}
```

On your main method just:

```
new WebsocketServer().start();
```

You might need to manipulate your code to fit it with this implementation, but that should be part of the job.

Here is the test output with 2 tests:

```
New connection from 127.0.0.1
Message from client: Ping
Closed connection to 127.0.0.1
New connection from 127.0.0.1
Message from client: Ping
```

---

here is WebSocket maven configuration, otherwise download the JAR file/s manually and import it in your IDE/development environment:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.java-websocket/Java-WebSocket -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.java-websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>Java-WebSocket</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Link to [WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket).

Comment: That website isn't up anymore. Is there any way to find that API elsewhere? @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Thanks!

Comment: @JaredScarito here is the link https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket I do not know why the site is down, but if you use maven it gone make your day smoother. good luck

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ You're awesome! Thanks so much!

Comment: I have been struggling with this for days. THANK YOU