# Forwarding User IP through Nginx at Websocket

Tags: java, nginx, websocket

I'm using [this Websocket library](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) with the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470482/java-server-javascript-client-websockets) to create multiple services based on websockets.

The main server taking the requests is an Nginx server which forwards the requests acording to their origin (domain based), so I can know for sure the requests received are for websockets.

The problem however is here:

```
public void onOpen(WebSocket ws, ClientHandshake handshake) {
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
    System.out.println(ws.getRemoteSocketAddress());
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");
}
```

**getRemoteSocketAddress** will always return the nginx server IP, something like **/192.168.1.100:43556**

My nginx configuration is:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name we.mydomain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access-ws-debug.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error-ws-debug.log;

    set_real_ip_from  192.168.1.0/24;
    real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
    real_ip_recursive on;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://192.168.1.101:54321;

       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host; #host
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Y-Real-IP $realip_remote_addr;

       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

       proxy_connect_timeout 1d;
       proxy_send_timeout 1d;
       proxy_read_timeout 1d;
    }
}
```

Is there any problem with the nxing configuration? Or is there any other way to get the IP of the user behind the websocket?

---

Solved thanks to Mark's answer. The following code is not related to the library mentioned. It's the "classic" web implementation in jsp without any library.

I modified the handshake to look like this:

```
@Override
public void modifyHandshake(
        ServerEndpointConfig config,
        HandshakeRequest request,
        HandshakeResponse response
) {
    HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) request.getHttpSession();
    config.getUserProperties().put(HttpSession.class.getName(), httpSession);
    config.getUserProperties().put("Headers",request.getHeaders());
}
```

And to get the Headers, just invoking this in the OnOpen:

```
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(final Session session, EndpointConfig config){ //This happens when javascript opens socket session
    Object list = config.getUserProperties().get("Headers");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
}
```

The returned format for the headers is like the following (using my phone):

```
{upgrade=[websocket], 
accept-language=[en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8], 
cookie=[JSESSIONID=0BAE99DFDE5DD81D20CFF04E4257D7FE], 
sec-websocket-extensions=[permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits], 
origin=[https://mywebsite.com], 
x-forwarded-for=[1.2.3.4], 
sec-websocket-version=[13], 
pragma=[no-cache], 
x-real-ip=[1.2.3.4], 
y-real-ip=[1.2.3.4], 
host=[mywebsite.com], 
connection=[Upgrade], 
sec-websocket-key=[ZroOewrBGrg660x7ocI+nog==], 
cache-control=[no-cache], 
accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate, br], 
user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-N950F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.80 Mobile Safari/537.36]}
```

And the IP is geo-localizable near my area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a trivial task to do, but your configuration looks OK you just have to get the original IP from the header you set (`X-Real-IP`).

```
import javax.websocket.*;
import javax.websocket.server.HandshakeRequest;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/test", configurator = Test.TestConfiguratior.class)
public class Test extends Endpoint {

    @Override
    public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig endpointConfig) {
        Object o = endpointConfig.getUserProperties().get(TestConfiguratior.HEADER_NAME);
        //o should be the string object you are looking for
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, String msg) {
        //do what u want
    }

    public static class TestConfiguratior extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {
        static String HEADER_NAME = "X-Real-IP";

        @Override
        public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig sec, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {
            String firstFoundHeader = request.getHeaders().get(HEADER_NAME.toLowerCase()).get(0);
            sec.getUserProperties().put(HEADER_NAME, firstFoundHeader);
        }
    }
}
```

TL.DR.: You can use the `javax.websocket.EndpointConfig#getUserProperties` map to put data in it and retrieve it later. Initially I thought that this can cause some concurrency problems while using this exact code, but I was not able to reproduce it. Even the documentation recommends to do so this way: 
https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/websocket010.html

***Update:*** This is a `JSR 356` example, not specific for the mentioned framework.

Comment: what concurrency problems could this cause?

Comment: Basically `ServerEndpointConfig.getUserProperties()` is "global". If there are many concurrent incoming connections you can override this value before you read it. So the code is OK for having a proof of concept, but *not OK for production* in my opinion. If you do not want to use any CDI stuff you can experiment with `ThreadLocal` as well, but I would prefer to use some Context instead.

Comment: could you update your example with how would you implement it for production? That would be great once we hit production stage, will also help people looking for this in a future. Many thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I'll do it tomorrow when I'll be in front of my machine. Are you in a CDI container?

Comment: Well I was trying to reproduce the concurrency problem but without luck.. maybe I remembered incorrectly. Even the JEE documentation, uses what I have recommended: https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/websocket010.html